# Flutter random string

Tags: flutter

i' m trying to display notification who has random strings who are stored in a List, everything is working but the problem is when i press allow to display notifications, it only show the same string from the list is not updating as i want to show another string that previous one. Here is the code:

```
String? randomYou;
    String? randomName;
    Color? randomColor;
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final random = new Random();
    randomName = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];
    randomYou = random1[random.nextInt(random1.length)];
```

```
 onPressed: () {
                          showToast();
                          NotificationService()
                              .showNotification(1, 'Hello', randomName!);
                        },
```

> I had tried with setState but it s not updating

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate the random string

1. Create a function to generate the random strings

```
generateStrings() {
  final random = new Random();
  randomName = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];
  randomYou = random1[random.nextInt(random1.length)];
}
```

2. Call the function before you show the notification

```
onPressed: () {
   generateStrings(); // Regenerate the string each time the button is pressed
   showToast();
   NotificationService()
     .showNotification(1, 'Hello', randomName!);
},
```

Comment: but i want to be updated without touching the button every time, i want when i press the button only one time the string to be updated every minute, hour, day and so on

Comment: If you want to update the string periodically then you should use a Timer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to push a function that generates random string? Like:

```
String RandomGenerator(){
   return "YourRandomString";
}
```

and

```
onPressed: () {
                  showToast();
                  NotificationService()
                 .showNotification(1, 'Hello', RandomGenerator();
                },
```